# Procedures giving error : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
CREATE TABLE product
( product_id number(10) NOT NULL,
  product_name varchar2(50) NOT NULL,
  price varchar2(50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p1 (product_id in number,
  product_name in varchar2,
  price in number) 

IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product values(1,'yash',100);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE INSERTED');

end;
```

Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

Can someone please provide me and suitable example

Comment: Maybe `INSERT INTO product values(1,'yash',100);` is what you want? Your procedure doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Apart from the main subject, you'd better to store the `price` in such a format : `NUMBER(10,2)` rather than `VARCHAR2` . Btw, you're even inserting the value in a numeric format.

Comment: Which of the two statements gives the error, `create table product` or `create or replace procedure p1`? If it's the procedure, is there anything else in that schema with the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, the name `p1` is already in use (*as an object name whose type is different than a procedure*). Just give the procedure a different (and more descriptive!) name:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE insert_product 
 (product_id in number,
  product_name in varchar2,
  price in number) 

IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO product values(1,'yash',100);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('VALUE INSERTED');
END;
```

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the `or replace` would help if there was already a **procedure** with that name. You'd get the same error if there was a different object with that name (e.g. a table or a view)

Comment: hmm you're right for name of an other type of objects.

Answer (score 1):

For your this problem the solution is write the following line (EXECUTE p1;)
By typing this command you will get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

You have twice asked for a 'suitable example' or 'justifying code'.  I assume from that you don't understand or don't believe what has been explained  about your procedure name conflicting with some other object name.    So here's the example that proves it.

```
SQL> --
SQL> -- check that we don't own anything called MYTEST
SQL> --
SQL> select object_name
  2  from user_objects
  3  where upper(object_name) = 'MYTEST'
  4  ;

no rows selected

SQL> --
SQL> -- create a table MYTEST
SQL> --
SQL> create table mytest (dob date);

Table created.

SQL> --
SQL> -- check objets
SQL> --
SQL> select object_type,
  2         object_name
  3  from user_objects
  4  where upper(object_name) = 'MYTEST'
  5  ;

OBJECT_TYPE         OBJECT_NAME
------------------- --------------------
TABLE               MYTEST

1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> -- create a procedure MYTEST
SQL> --
SQL> create or replace procedure mytest
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
  5  end;
  6  /
create or replace procedure mytest
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL> --
SQL> -- now, drop the table and try the procedure again
SQL> --
SQL> drop table mytest purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> create or replace procedure mytest
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> --
SQL> -- cleanup
SQL> --
SQL> drop table mytest purge;
drop table mytest purge
           *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist


SQL> drop procedure mytest;

Procedure dropped.
```

In your case if your procedure is named 'p1' then check:

```
select object_type,
       object_name
from user_objects
where upper(object_name) = 'P1'
;
```